# Calculation of $ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{a^2+2a\cos\theta+1}}{(a\cos\theta+1)^2} d\theta $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

This integral formula came from the calculation in the spherical coordinate. Here, $a$ is a real number greater than 1.
$$ I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{a^2+2a\cos\theta+1}}{(a\cos\theta+1)^2}d\theta $$
Since $a^2+2a\cos\theta+1=\mathrm{Re}(a+e^{i\theta})(a+e^{-i\theta})$ and $a\cos\theta+1=\mathrm{Re}(ae^{i\theta}+1)$, the integration becomes
$$ I = \mathrm{Re}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{(a+e^{i\theta})(a+e^{-i\theta})}}{(ae^{i\theta}+1)^2}d\theta. $$
Substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$ yields
$$ I = \mathrm{Re}\oint_C \frac{\sqrt{(a+z)(a+1/z)}}{iz(az+1)^2}dz, $$
where $C$ is an unit circle centered at the origin.

At this moment, I tried to decompose the integrand into partial fractions and to use Cauchy's integral formula, but the numerator of integrand, $\sqrt{(a+z)(a+1/z)}$, is not continuous on $C$ because of the multivaluedness of complex square root. How can I approach to the next step?

Comment: Can you post the spherical coordinates integral? There might be a way to change the order of integration to get an easier integral. You can post it as a separate question if you would still like to know how to do this integral separately.

Comment: The original integral is double integral w.r.t. polar angle $\phi$ and azimuth angle 
 $\theta$, but unfortunately the integrand does not contain polar angle.

Comment: Still, if it is a surface integral there may be tricks around that

Comment: It diverges. $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{f}\left(\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)
\,\mathrm{d}\theta =
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left[\mathrm{f}\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right) + \color{red}{\mathrm{f}\left(-\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)}\right]
\,\mathrm{d}\theta$. The $\color{red}{red\ term}$ yields a divergenge when $\displaystyle\sin\left(\theta\right) = 1/a$ with $\displaystyle a > 1$.

Comment: For $a \in [0,1)$ the integral converges and its value seems to be $\frac{4 \operatorname{E} (a)}{1-a^2}$ ($\operatorname{E}$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind)), but I have not found a proof yet.

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial  There is a sentence in the OP first line: "$\color{red}{\mbox{Here,}\ \color{black}{a}\
\mbox{ is a real number greater than}\ 1.}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Felix Marin in comments, **the integral diverges for $a\ge1$**. However we shall verify ComplexYetTrivial's claim that $I=\frac{4E(a^2)}{1-a^2}$ if $a\in[0,1)$. Elliptic integrals follow Mathematica/mpmath conventions in this answer.

Using Byrd and Friedman 289.09:
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{a^2+2a\cos\theta+1}}{(a\cos\theta+1)^2}\,d\theta=2\int_0^\pi\frac{a^2+1+2a\cos\theta}{(a\cos\theta+1)^2}\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+1+2a\cos\theta}}\,d\theta\newcommand{sn}{\operatorname{sn}}$$
$$=\frac4{a+1}\int_0^{K(m=4a/(a+1)^2)}\frac{a^2+1+2a(1-2\sn^2u)}{(a(1-2\sn^2u)+1)^2}\,du$$
$$=\frac4{(a+1)^2}\int_0^{K(m)}\left(\frac{a-1}{(1-\frac{2a}{a+1}\sn^2u)^2}+\frac2{1-\frac{2a}{a+1}\sn^2u}\right)\,du$$
Now using B&F 336.01 and .02:
$$\int_0^\varphi\frac1{1-n\sn^2u}\,du=\Pi(n,\varphi,m)$$
$$\int_0^\varphi\frac1{(1-n\sn^2u)^2}\,du=\frac1{2(n-1)(m-n)}\left(nE(\varphi,m)+(m-n)F(\varphi,m)+(2mn+2n-n^2-3m)\Pi(n,\varphi,m)-\frac{n^2\sn u\operatorname{cn}u\operatorname{dn}u}{1-n\sn^2u}\right)$$
we get after much simplification (note that $\varphi=\pi/2$ here)
$$I=2\left(\frac{K(m)}{a+1}-\frac{E(m)}{a-1}\right)$$
which is in turn simplified by a Gauss transformation to
$$I=\frac{4E(a^2)}{1-a^2}$$